# JQuery .ajax dosen't work with http://127.0.0.1:5984

Tags: jquery, ajax, couchdb

Help me with my problem,please!
I used CouchDB, and i used jquery.couch.js to communicate with a CouchDB server (http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/index.html) 
but it's dosen't work(( Start of such script:

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'
function getAllDBs(){
    $.couch.db('mysecondtest').allDocs({
        error: function(status, id, reason) {alert(status+' : '+id+' : '+reason);},
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }

    });
}
getAllDBs();
```

return an error:

```
405 Method Not Allowed localhost:5984
```

I think, it means that the server perceives my request as request about the remote server, but I don't know as to correct it. Please help me and sorry for my bad English))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are falling into a cross-domain issue.

You may consider using [couchdb-xd](https://github.com/benvinegar/couchdb-xd)

Comment: Whenever there's cross-domain issue, you have to consider JSONP instead

Comment: It can be possible as that to get rid from cross-domain?

Comment: Probably you cannot as couchdb runs on different port even if on the same server.

Comment: Please read more on cross-site scripting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: thancks for couchdb-xd, i will use it)

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct for other people know about it

Comment: @AbdulMunim: The error says "method not allowed". Why would that imply a cross domain issue? This surely means our questioner is doing say OPTIONS or PUT where the server only supports GET.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests cannot happen cross-server per design. This is of security-reasons.

Comment: i know, but i don't use cross-server. it's localhost!

Comment: cross-server is also across ports.

Comment: Whether use proxy will help to correct it? And if yes, as it to make?