# jQuery Ajax 404 error from javascript to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to do an ajax call from a javascript file to a PHP file. 
 This is the code i have:

```
function testAjax()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:81/Gorillo/account/test',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(err)
            {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        })

    }
```

The function in the PHP file:

```
function test()
{
    echo "hello";
}
```

In my browser console i get the following error upon running the code:

```
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}
```

However, when i use XDebug to debug the code, i can see the PHP code is being executed by placing breakpoints. This means the ajax call does find the PHP file/function.
 Why do i get a 404 error?
Regards

Comment: can you open the url in your browser?

Comment: 404 Error means the webserver could not complete the request because the file was not found. try opening the url in the browser.

Comment: is it possible that your php should be `....test.php` or `.....test/index.php`?

Comment: When i visit the url in de browser, it shows the echo message.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241911/jquery-ajax-dosent-work-with-http-127-0-0-15984   try `url: 'http://localhost:81/url` or simply `url: '/Gorillo/account/test'`

Comment: @TanuelMategi the url changes don't work. What do you mean with cross domain issue? It seems far fetched because i can make ajax calls from another javascript file perfectly fine.

Comment: This is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: @skywalker I tried the things you suggested in the post, it still does the same. In the PHP file i now check what $_GET contains. When i debug my PHP code, the function still gets executed, but the call still returns 404. Could it be that i am not returning data the proper way?